Is a "Dune: Part Three" in the works?
Last night I finished Dune: Part Two—which ended when Paul sent the Fremen warriors to ships to attack the ships of the great houses orbiting Arrakis—do they plan to end the series at that or is there going to be a follow-up to this?

It's been said and written for months now that there was a Dune part III on the grill, so a simple search would self-answer the question. So if it's on-topic, it's still open to be closed as low-quality job :)

I’m voting to close this question because it's low quality and title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series are off-topic (https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

@Luciano - OP is not looking for rumours, nor are they after a release date. They wish to know if it's been official confirmed.

@Luciano - And poor quality is a reason to downvote, not to close. Please don't use the close vote as a super-downvote

I think there's a bit of misunderstanding, cause by imperfect wrapping of the film. This is a two part thing. Eventual sequel is gonna show much later events. Paul's JIhad is not gonna be depicted.

@Mithoron - It'll almost certainly be depicted in some form, to explain to audiences what's been happening. I'd imagine we'll get flashbacks or some such device to give us some emotional and informational context.

@Valorum Yeah, I guess, but OP seemed to think there's gonna be some "Dune III Paul's war" or some-such, which isn't the case.

@Mithoron - Never say never. Who'd'a'thunk we'd ever get to see them stealing the Death Star plans?

@Valorum Hmm, I think there was some of the war shown in one of unfortunate "new books"... Hopefully it won't come to pass anytime soon.

In a word, yes. Dune, Part III (Based on the novel Dune Messiah) has been officially greenlit. Given the success of the previous two movies, it's highly likely that it will progress into production, probably for release in 2026 or 2027.

‘Dune: Messiah’ Officially Confirmed!
But, as you might have assumed, the wait is now over. Legendary
Pictures has officially confirmed that the production of the third and
final Dune film, Dune: Messiah (tentative title, the official one has
not been revealed), has been greenlit, which means that Villeneuve can
begin work on the movie, for which a script has already been written.
Fiction Horizon

Villeneuve confirmed that the project was in its infancy, but off the table.

“I think you cannot avoid Paul’s terrible purpose, that’s the
structure of this whole enterprise. Saying this, I do not like to
comment on Dune Messiah because I’m writing it, and when I’m writing,
I love to shut up because it’s a very delicate time where things are
fragile, ideas evolve. I like to talk about movies when they are
alive, finished, and strong enough to walk by themselves. Dune Messiah
is barely an embryo.”
“Things Are Fragile”: Dune 3 Gets Cautious Update From Denis Villeneuve As Part 2 Hits Big

